# Bash/ Awk/ Sed capture the last third and fourth line info in each file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

We are trying to use awk/bash/sed to get the last third and fourth value of "DV/DL" of multiple files (input1.dat, input2.dat, input3.dat) and print out DV/DL incrementally from "input1.dat", "input1.dat input2.dat", "input1.dat input2.dat input3.dat",etc.

The "input1.dat" output will be

```
"the fourth last DV/DL in input1.dat"  "the third last DV/DL in input1.dat"
```

The "input1.dat input2.dat " output will be

```
"the fourth last DV/DL in input1.dat"  "the third last DV/DL in input1.dat"
"the fourth last DV/DL in input2.dat"  "the third last DV/DL in input2.dat"
```

The example file (input1.dat) is below.  In input1.dat we would like to print out "DV/DL" as "-26.2720  2.6879".

```
NSTEP =    50000   TIME(PS) =     450.000  TEMP(K) =   299.02  PRESS =   213.4
Etot   =    -80270.1079  EKtot   =     33984.2399  EPtot      =   -114254.3478
BOND   =     22963.8665  ANGLE   =      2030.3803  DIHED      =      4232.0101
1-4 NB =       953.1576  1-4 EEL =     12610.8610  VDWAALS    =     20829.7086
EELEC  =   -177874.3319  EHBOND  =         0.0000  RESTRAINT  =         0.0000
DV/DL  =       -26.2168
EKCMT  =     10196.0704  VIRIAL  =      8501.7871  VOLUME     =    367647.0872
                                                Density    =         1.0555
Ewald error estimate:   0.3945E-04
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  A V E R A G E S   O V E R   50000 S T E P S


NSTEP =    50000   TIME(PS) =     450.000  TEMP(K) =   299.79  PRESS =     2.0
Etot   =    -80333.0001  EKtot   =     34071.3290  EPtot      =   -114404.3291
BOND   =     22903.8667  ANGLE   =      2081.5119  DIHED      =      4220.2140
1-4 NB =       932.2502  1-4 EEL =     12548.7169  VDWAALS    =     20862.9158
EELEC  =   -177953.8046  EHBOND  =         0.0000  RESTRAINT  =         0.0000
**DV/DL  =       -26.2720**
EKCMT  =     10189.4552  VIRIAL  =     10173.6800  VOLUME     =    367385.1338
                                                Density    =         1.0562
Ewald error estimate:   0.4704E-04
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


R M S  F L U C T U A T I O N S


NSTEP =    50000   TIME(PS) =     450.000  TEMP(K) =     1.28  PRESS =   145.5
Etot   =       231.2453  EKtot   =       145.6638  EPtot      =       184.9663
BOND   =       151.1551  ANGLE   =        35.0649  DIHED      =        19.6523
1-4 NB =        12.6972  1-4 EEL =        33.8995  VDWAALS    =       174.9784
EELEC  =       305.7204  EHBOND  =         0.0000  RESTRAINT  =         0.0000
**DV/DL  =         2.6879**
EKCMT  =        78.6868  VIRIAL  =      1152.6836  VOLUME     =       406.3321
                                                Density    =         0.0012
Ewald error estimate:   0.3520E-04
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


**DV/DL**, AVERAGES OVER   50000 STEPS


NSTEP =    50000   TIME(PS) =     450.000  TEMP(K) =     0.00  PRESS =     0.0
Etot   =         0.0000  EKtot   =         0.0000  EPtot      =       -26.2720
BOND   =         0.0000  ANGLE   =         0.0000  DIHED      =         0.0000
1-4 NB =         0.0000  1-4 EEL =        -8.4978  VDWAALS    =         0.0000
EELEC  =       -17.7743  EHBOND  =         0.0000  RESTRAINT  =         0.0000
DV/DL  =       -26.2720
Ewald error estimate:   0.0000E+00


    ___________________
```

The following one is our first attempt.

```
for X in 1 2 3

do

var1='awk -f capture_dvdl.awk'
var2="$var2 input${X}.dat"
var3=">> output${X}.dat"

echo "$var1 $var2 $var3"  > average_preparation.sh

sh average_preparation.sh

done
```

capture_dvdl.awk is here

```
#!/bin/awk

BEGIN{}
{
if ($1 ~ /^DV\/DL/ && FNR == 2603) {

printf("%14.4f",$3)

 }

 }

 {
 if ($1 ~ /^DV\/DL/ && FNR == 2618) {

 printf("%14.4f\n",$3)

 }

 }
```

This will generate average_preparation.sh as

```
awk -f capture_dvdl.awk input1.dat > output1.dat

awk -f capture_dvdl.awk input1.dat input2.dat > output2.dat
```

However, the last third and fourth "DV/DL" are not necessary in the line of 2603 and 2618, so this trick doesn't work.

The second trick is this

```
 awk '$1 ~ /^DV\/DL/ {printf("%14.4f\n",$3)}' input1.dat input2.dat input3.dat | tail -n 4 | head -n 2 > output.dat
```

However, this one will only print out the last third and fourth DV/DL of input3.dat.

Wonder if any guru could kindly offer any comment?  Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "last third and fourth"? Your example seems to correspond with either "the third and fourth" or "the last two" instances of DV/DL.

Comment: Hello rici, sorry I was still editing the post.   The last third and fourth value of "DV/DL" here means the "-26.2720 2.6879" in the example 1 file.

Comment: HenrySu: Yeah, you said that. But what exactly determines which two values need to be printed out? I suppose you're not showing all of the input file, since your question says they are at lines 2603 and 2618, so there might be more DV/DL lines before and after the excerpt. In short, the example is more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Also, it doesn't help that DV/DL = -26.2720 occurs twice in the example file, so even if it were the entire file, it wouldn't be clear which line you were talking about.

Comment: Hello rici, yes! -26.2720 occurs several times at the end of file.  Is there anyway that I can highlight the input1.dat?  I tried to make it bold but always failed.

Comment: Don't post a sample input file with repeated numbers as that makes it MUCH harder for us to understand your question so we can help you. Any time you find yourself writing a loop in shell just to parse text files, you have the wrong approach. If those `**`s in the input are your attempt to make some text bold, remove them as they can't work and obfuscate the question even more. When you say `last third and fourth`, do you mean `third, fourth and last` or do you mean `third-last and fourth-last` or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a very simple problem described in a very complicated way. Let's start with this:

```
$ awk '/DV\/DL.*=/{val[++cnt]=$NF} END{for (i=1;i<=cnt;i++) print i, val[i]}' file
1 -26.2168
2 -26.2720
3 2.6879
4 -26.2720

$ awk '/DV\/DL.*=/{val[++cnt]=$NF} END{print "third:", val[3]}' file
third: 2.6879

$ awk '/DV\/DL.*=/{val[++cnt]=$NF} END{print "third-last:", val[cnt-3]}' file
third-last: -26.2168

$ awk '/DV\/DL.*=/{val[++cnt]=$NF} END{print "last:", val[cnt]}' file
last: -26.2720
```

Now - what do you need done differently and why?

The above was produced from your posted input file with the `**`s removed from the DV/DL lines as I THINK you added that to try to make the text bold (if so, remove that as it's making things even more confusing).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the precise wording of the question ("third and fourth last") and the example code which shows the target text as starting at column 1, this might work:

```
for f in input1.dat input2.dat input3.dat; do
  echo $(awk '/^DV\/DL/{printf "%14.4f\n",$3}' $f | tail -n4 | head -n2)
done
```

If the filenames are easy to generate with a pattern, as above, you can use that:

```
for f in input?.dat; do
  echo $(awk '/^DV\/DL/{printf "%14.4f\n",$3}' $f | tail -n4 | head -n2)
done
```

If you want them to be printed in the opposite order, add `| tac` after the `head -n2`

Comment: Hello we try both but sadly nothing is generated. Wonder if there is any comment? Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible for that script to produce no output if your real input follows the format of your posted sample input. Check the difference between what you told us your input looks like and what it really looks like and update your question.

Comment: I think @EdMorton is correct; the script should certainly have produced some output as long as some line in some iput file starts with the characters `DV/DL`. I missed a `\n` in the printf format (now corrected), so it would have printed all the DV/DL values instead of the first two of the last four, but still *something*. If `DV/DL` are not literally the first five characters of the line (perhaps there is a space in front), you'll have to adjust the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

4th than 3th as request

```
sed -n '\|^DV/DL| H
$ {x;s|\nDV/DL *= *|;|g;s/\([^;]*;\)\{2\}\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\);.*/\3 \2/p;}' YourFile
2.6879 -26.2720
```

3th and 4th like your sample

```
sed -n '\|^DV/DL| H
$ {x;s|\nDV/DL *= *|;|g;s/\([^;]*;\)\{2\}\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\);.*/\2 \3/p;}' YourFile
-26.2720 2.6879
```

Comment: Hello we try both but sadly nothing is generated. Wonder if there is any comment? Thanks.

Comment: maybe use the `-e` and eventually `--posix`, i test on my AIX/KSH